# Differences in the Drawings of Fourier Series

Tags: fourier-series, graphing-functions

I have a general question about the appearances of Fourier Series, and I was wondering if anyone could help me with this. Let us have a function, say $f(x)=e^x$, and let us have the Fourier Sine Series, Fourier Cosine Series, and the Full Fourier Series (General Fourier Series) of $e^x$ on a graph from $x\in(-3,3)$. My question is, how do these Fourier Series differ in appearance, especially on such a small scale? I would assume that they would all be very close to the function $e^x$ on this interval, would there be any distinguishing features between the 3 that would stand out?

Comment: Well, any Fourier sine series is an odd function and any Fourier cosine series is an even function. Since $e^x$ is neither odd or even on $(-3,3)$, neither the Fourier sine series or the Fourier cosine series are expected to be pointwise convergent, for instance.

Comment: What would that look like?

Comment: The Fourier sine series converges to $\sinh(x)$ (the odd part of $e^x$) and the Fourier cosine series converges to $\cosh(x)$ (the even part of $e^x$). Their sum converges (uniformly) to $e^x$.

Comment: My [blog post](https://calculus7.org/2013/11/04/down-with-sines/) has plots of all of them, for $e^x$ on $(-1, 1)$. I don't think $(-3, 3)$ would be any more informative.